# Anybody have idea about javafx turn-based game loop and event handling?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, javafx-2, game-loop

I've been doing turn-based battle game that wait for user response before doing action.
So the game loop must be depends on opponent's health or our health not on frame rate.

Is anyone have any idea about this. Because I did something like this

```
@FXML
private void run() {
    while(!isWinning) {
         if (isAttackButtonPressed) {
             attack();
             isAttackButtonPressed = false;
         else if (isDefendButtonPressed) {
             defend();
         ...
    }
    System.out.println(getWinner());
}
```

And it stuck forever.

Comment: I haven't created game before, but I hope [this](https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/introduction-to-javafx-for-game-development--cms-23835) will be useful for you.

Comment: Don't write a loop. Just use event handlers to update the current state of the game. Search for something like "JavaFX tic tac toe" to see if you can find examples.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/yfain/java24hourtrainer2ndedition/tree/master/TicTacToe)'s a  pretty simple example of a turn-based game.

Comment: Maybe the FXGL
could work for you.